# Python Integer -> Object store

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pickle, key-value

I'm looking for solution to store huge (to big for RAM) array-like/list-like object on HDD. So, basically I'm looking for key-value database with:
- integer (not string!) keys
- ability to store python objects (list of tuples). Appended object will never be changed. There is no relation betweeen objects in array. 
- low memory usage (no caching). If I need to load 35235235th object, I want to load only it.

So, I could use SQLite and blobs, but I'm looking for something more elegant and very fast.

Sorry for my bad english. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: How about [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin/PyTables)?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at zodb http://www.zodb.org, which is a mature python db project. It has the  [btrees package](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/documentation/guide/modules.html#btrees-package), which provides the IOBTree, which is what you might be looking for.

Comment: I was trying to use zodb with something like this:
root["data"] -> PersistenList. But when i was loading root["data"][4334325], it loaded whole list into memory. I will try use IOBTree.